# sqlite update table to view new results inserted into database

Tags: php

I have a database which I have already inserted new entries in. I am now stuck trying to store the textarea input as a new $var, inserting this into the table, then updating the new table results, all on the submit button click event. here's my code so far. the loop works fine for the previous entered entries. It just will not update for some reason.

```
<?php
session_start();

$db=sqlite_open("MainDB.db");

$result=sqlite_query($db,"SELECT * FROM stock");

$user ="tea";

$result=sqlite_query($db,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE ProductName = '$user'");

if( sqlite_num_rows($result))
{
    echo "<table border=1>\n";
    echo "<h2>". $user. " messages"."</h2>";
    echo "</br>\n";
    echo "<th>Sender</th>\n";
}
while($row=sqlite_fetch_array($result,SQLITE_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

sqlite_close($db);
?>

<html>
    <body>

        <form action = "testdatabase.php" method="POST">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Then here is the insert code

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $db=sqlite_open("MainDB.db");

  header("location: testdatabase.php");

   $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];

   $message = $_SESSION['message']

   $result=sqlite_query($db,"SELECT * FROM stock");
   $result=sqlite_num_rows(sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM stock"));

   sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO stock (ProductName) VALUES('$message')");


   ?>
```

Comment: Where is the code to *update*?

Comment: sorry i forgot that part

Comment: I have updated now Lawrence

Comment: You are moving away from the code with `header("location: testdatabase.php");` before you get to the `sqlite_query`. That is probably why. Why did you put the header there in the first place?